# Python divide odd length string and combine

Tags: python

I'm going through the free Python class Google has available ([Link if interested)](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) and I'm stuck on one of the exercises.

Goal:
Consider dividing a string into two halves.
If the length is even, the front and back halves are the same length.
If the length is odd, we'll say that the extra char goes in the front half.
e.g. 'abcde', the front half is 'abc', the back half 'de'.
Given 2 strings, a and b, return a string of the form
 a-front + b-front + a-back + b-back

This is what I have so far:

```
def front_back(a, b):
    if len(a)%2 == 0 or len(b)%2 == 0:
        firstpart , secondpart = a[:len(a)/2] , a[len(a)/2:]
        thirdpart , fourthpart = b[:len(b)/2] , b[len(b)/2:]
    else:
        firstpart , secondpart = a[:len(a)+1/2] , a[len(a)+1/2:]
        thirdpart , fourthpart = b[:len(b)+1/2] , b[len(b)+1/2:]
    return firstpart+thirdpart+secondpart+fourthpart
```

These are the test strings:

```
 test(front_back('abcd', 'xy'), 'abxcdy')
 test(front_back('abcde', 'xyz'), 'abcxydez')
 test(front_back('Kitten', 'Donut'), 'KitDontenut')
```

The third string in each is the expected string.

What am I doing wrong? I know that the issue is not being able to account for odd-length strings, but I have been searching for a few days now and I've had no luck finding an answer online. I'm also open to more efficient solutions, but I want to know why my particular setup is not working out, for future reference.

Thanks!

Comment: Your order of operations is not correct.  Should be `(len(a)+1)/2`

Comment: @dansalmo I actually tried that as well to fix the order of operations. That tests correct for the first two cases, but gives "  X  got: 'KitDotennut' expected: 'KitDontenut'" for the last one. Any ideas why?

Comment: The only formula you need is `(len(a)+1)/2`.  It works for both the even and odd case due to how integer division and slicing works in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler method:

```
def front_back(a, b):
    hlena, hlenb = (len(a) + 1)/2, (len(b) + 1)/2
    return a[:hlena] + b[:hlenb] + a[hlena:] + b[hlenb:]
```

No need for `if` clause to handle empty string case.  Order of operations for slice calculation was not correct in your code.

Tip: Defore diving in and coding, play with the problem in the REPL shell until you have a succinct representation of the problem.  One of the biggest challenges that beginners have is the code they create is much larger than needed, making it harder to understand and debug.  Start  with the smallest workable chuck and build from there.

Comment: I am amazed by the simplicity of your solution. Even though I got 3 other right answers at about the same time, I think I will go with yours simply because of how concise it is. Thank you!

Comment: This will come across as pretty stupid but by REPL shell do you just mean the Terminal (in OSX) and running Python, or is there a more convenient way? I would actually love that, I've only done HTML+CSS before and there you can test instantly (especially with LiveReload), and lack of that in Python is slightly cumbersome. *Edit: Using PyCharm, if that makes a difference to your answer

Comment: Yes, I use Idle and IPython.  I spend more time doing interactive code snippet checking than I do creating the final code.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're not treating a and b as separate cases.  Consider the case where a has length 4 and b has length 5.  In that case you would always take the first branch, which would treat b incorrectly.

```
def front_back(a, b):
    if len(a)%2 == 0:
        firstpart , secondpart = a[:len(a)/2] , a[len(a)/2:]
    else:
        firstpart , secondpart = a[:len(a)+1/2] , a[len(a)+1/2:]

    if len(b)%2 == 0:
        thirdpart , fourthpart = b[:len(b)+1/2] , b[len(b)+1/2:]
    else
        thirdpart , fourthpart = b[:len(b)/2] , b[len(b)/2:]

    return firstpart+thirdpart+secondpart+fourthpart
```

Comment: Still having the same issue unfortunately. Test results:

  X  got: 'abxycd' expected: 'abxcdy'
  X  got: 'abcdexyz' expected: 'abcxydez'
  X  got: 'KitDotennut' expected: 'KitDontenut'

Answer (score 2):

You should split the implementation into a splitting function and a merging. Easier to test that way. Also, the way the split is defined, you can simplify the first function quite a bit:

If the length of the string s is even, `len(s)//2` in integer division is the same as `(len(s)+1)//2`. If it is odd, `len(s)//2` is one less than `(len(s)+1)//2`. Since you need the longer string as first part, the splitting function can be written as:

```
def splitter(s):
    mid = (len(s)+1)//2
    return s[:mid], s[mid:]
```

Then for the merging:

```
def front_back(a,b):
    a_front, a_back = splitter(a)
    b_front, b_back = splitter(b)
    return "".join((a_front, b_front, a_back, b_back))
```

Comment: very nice tip on the integer division!

Comment: Great explanation and great tip on integer division as @msturdy said. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try to avoid repeating code.. if you're splitting one string once, and then following the same rules to split a second string, just write a small function to do it!  I've put a function called `splitter()` inside the main function `front_back()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def front_back(a, b):

  def splitter(s):
    l = len(s)
    if l%2 == 0:
      d = l/2
    else:
      d = (l/2) +1
    return (s[:d], s[d:])

  a1, a2 = splitter(a)
  b1, b2 = splitter(b)

  return a1 + b1 + a2 + b2
```

try that out...

Comment: Thank you for the tip on not repeating code, when you're trying to hack together a solution you forget such simple advice :)